# DNS not working inside Ubuntu VM (running docker)

Tags: dns, proxmox

I have a VM managed by Proxmox that's running Ubuntu 20.04 (desktop) and is also running docker (with portainer). I can't get any dns resolution i.e. if I do `ping google.com` it says `Temporary failure in name resolution` (if I ping `8.8.8.8` it's fine). However, if I do it in another VM that has identical OS and Proxmox settings, it pings fine.

In both VMs the `/etc/resolv.conf` file is identical; it just has the two lines (as well as a huge comment saying not to edit this file because it's managed dynamically):

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

The Proxmox node itself has two DNS IPs set; `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. Seems absurd that installing docker on one VM should nuke the DNS...

Answer (score 0):

So apparently, in /etc/systemd/resolv.conf I had uncommented the line that had DNSStubListener=no. Re-commenting that line fixes all my DNS issues. No idea why honestly, but at least it works. I wouldn't mind knowing why this works...